# jQuery FadeIn / FadeOut Methods not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to fade the image on hover.
Why does this not work?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lightbulb").hover(function(){
      $("#lightbulb").fadeOut('fast');
    },function(){
      $("#lightbulb").fadeIn();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Other jQuery methods like CSS styling and changing image sources are working.

Comment: Where is the `#lightbulb` element? Also, if the element is not faded out you won't be able to hover it at all, as it takes no space in the DOM

Comment: Rory McCrossan --> Thanks for the help! How do you suggest I go about this?

Comment: I don't know without seeing the information I asked for in my previous comment...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place the fadeOut() effect at the same element you add the hover() to.
fadeOut() sets the Element to "display: none;" and removes it from the DOM.
So a $fadeIn() effect can never take place, because the element with the $hover() targeted is gone.

You need to target a parent container with hover() and fadeIn() and fadeOut() the inner elements. That should work.

```
$("#parentbulb").hover(function(){
    $("#lightbulb").fadeOut('fast');
  },function(){
    $("#lightbulb").fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use css instead of jQuery if that works. When you fadeOut the element, the hover exit event is fired, so it will just keep toggling between the states the way you have it. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/587809/) with an example of hiding/showing on hover. Basically you do like

```
#elem {
     opacity: 1;
     transition: opacity: 0.2s;
}

#elem:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

on whichever element you want to hide.

Comment: That works fine, but I also want to change the source of the image gradually.